# How do I create a .storekit file in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm currently trying to set up a local environment to test in-app purchases in a macOS application.

Apple's documentation at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/setting_up_storekit_testing_in_xcode states:

> To create a StoreKit configuration file, launch Xcode, then choose File > New > File. In the sheet that appears, enter “storekit” in the Filter search field, select StoreKit Configuration File...

When I filter on "storekit", there is no "StoreKit Configuration File."

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to install some kind of SDK or similar in Xcode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use Xcode  12.0 beta (12A6159) on Catalina 10.15.5.
The Storekit configuration file is found and I can create and configure it.

But the Scheme -> Run -> Option does not display a selection option to perform local testing on a macOS project, but only on IOS project.

On the apple documentation StoreKit Test framework is labelled macOS 11.0+

A comment on Apple Dev Forum indicate that this menu appears on a Big Sur configuration for a macOS project, but that Xcode stills connects to Sandbox. Not tried yet on Big Sur.

Comment: You're right, looks like I can't use a .storekit file with a desktop application. Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same issue for Mac App running on MacOS 10.15 and attempting to use Xcode 12.0 Beta 5... so probably this does indeed require MacOS 11 to work.

Comment: @CliffRibaudo I could make it work with MacOS 10.15.6 (19G73), and XCode Version 12.0 beta 5 (12A8189h).
No idea where your issue come from though

Comment: @AmauryLiet it works for iOS NOT for MacOS Apps. It's in the Xcode 12.0 Beta 5 Release notes that Storekit configuration file requires MacOS 11 for MacApps

Comment: @CliffRibaudo oh yes indeed, I read the issue too fast - thanks for the correction

Answer (score 2):

One thing that can trip people up:

If you are using Swift Packages and you have any source-file or directory from a package selected in the Project Navigator, then the types available in the `File->New->File` sheet is more restricted.

Select the iOS project, or a Group within it, then `File->New->File` will contain the *StoreKit Configuration File* option.

Answer (score 0):

This is a brand new feature, so you need the latest version of Xcode for this - Xcode 12. Please also watch the session https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10659/